# Can't get the value of an php array key to display

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I am working on a wordpress theme and want a function to return the information of the last published post.

My function so far:

```
function get_last_post()
{
    
    $latest_post = new WP_Query("post_type=post&posts_per_page=1&orderby=date&order=DESC&post_status=publish");
    if($latest_post->have_posts())
    {
        reset($latest_post);
        $cur = current($latest_post);
       
        var_dump($cur);
        //var_dump($cur['']);
        $ret['title'] = $cur['post_title'];
        $ret['content'] = $cur['post_content'];;
        $ret['link'] = get_permalink($cur['ID']);
    }
     else {
        $ret['title'] = _e('Ni objav', 'responsive');
        $ret['content'] = _e('ni novih objav', 'responsive');
        $ret['link'] = '';
    }
 return $ret;
}
```

The problem is that I can't get the information from the array.

if I var_dump the array `var_dump($cur);` the information I want is there but can't seem to be able to grab it if I do `var_dump($cur['post_title'])` it returns `NULL` also I didn't find anything useful on this on the web.

The solution:

```
function get_last_post()
{
    $latest_post = new WP_Query("post_type=post&posts_per_page=1&orderby=date&order=DESC&post_status=publish");

    if($latest_post->have_posts())
    {
        $cur = $latest_post->posts;
        $cur = $cur[0];
       

        $ret['title'] = $cur->post_title;
        $ret['content'] = $cur->post_content;;
        $ret['link'] = get_permalink($cur->ID);
    }
    else {
        $ret['title'] = _e('Ni objav', 'responsive');
        $ret['content'] = _e('ni novih objav', 'responsive');
        $ret['link'] = '';
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the output from the `var_dump($cur);` please?

Comment: So, the array key exists and has a value when you use `var_dump($cur)`, but accessing the key directly using `$cur['post_title']` returns null? Please share the output of `var_dump($cur)`.

Comment: Thank's for the help sometimes a bit fresh air helps the thinking :) above is my solution I didn't notice that I get an array with an array of objects inside it. Solution is in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking I came up with this. Thank you for all the invested time.

**The solution:**

```
function get_last_post()
{

    $latest_post = new WP_Query("post_type=post&posts_per_page=1&orderby=date&order=DESC&post_status=publish");
    if($latest_post->have_posts())
    {
        $cur = $latest_post->posts;
        $cur = $cur[0];


        $ret['title'] = $cur->post_title;
        $ret['content'] = $cur->post_content;;
        $ret['link'] = get_permalink($cur->ID);
    }
     else {
        $ret['title'] = _e('Ni objav', 'responsive');
        $ret['content'] = _e('ni novih objav', 'responsive');
        $ret['link'] = '';
    }
 return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the details of the post you're looking for, you can do this:

```
$latest_query = new WP_Query("post_type=post&posts_per_page=1&orderby=date&order=DESC&post_status=publish");

if($latest_post->have_posts()) {
    $latest_post->the_post();
     ....
```

You can then get at the details of the post with the regular WordPress functions:

```
 echo "<h1>" . get_the_title() . "</h1>";
```

And so on.

Comment: I know I can do it this way but I whanted a function

Comment: You can wrap the code above in a function - you just need to replace the existing code.

Comment: I know just the idea was to get the array back from the function and use that in something else not to display it directly

Comment: I used `echo` as an example, though (and because that's the one they link to in the documents). If you've solved the problem yourself, you can add your own answer, and accept it.